# cefsharp c# зависает через день постоянной работы

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Приложение для информационного стенда использует для открытия сайтов библиотеку "cefsharp" в winforms. 
Через один-два дня непрерывной работы приложение зависает без ошибок.

```
public static ChromiumWebBrowser Browser;
public void InitializeChromium()
{
  Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
  Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.ru/")
  {
     Dock = DockStyle.None,
     Size = panel2.Size
  };
  Browser.MenuHandler = new MenuHandler();
  Browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
  Browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler();
  Browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnBrowserLoadingStateChanged;
}
```

Comment: Зависает без ошибок - значит, вы не ловите ошибки в try...catch и не знаете, ни того, что произошло (может не в cef проблема) ни в каком месте. Если вы действительно хотите разобраться, а не тыкать наугад по подсказкам астрологов и телепатов или искать "не там где потерял, а там где светло" - то вам нужно сначала локализовать точное место падения и ошибку. А этот вопрос нужно закрыть до выяснения обстоятельств.

Comment: Программа не выдает исключений, так как их нет, тру кетч не ловит зависание.

Comment: Если всё же дело в том, что я не ловлю исключения - то где мне их ловить? Этот код выполняется при запуске программы и отрабатывает без  ошибок, а дальше уже ловить ошибки где - не знаю, ибо браузер всё делает сам.